# Comparing double[] and int. Help would be great

Tags: c#

Hi there I am needing help as I am trying to compare a double[] and an int. I know this does not work and i am needing advice as to how I should go ahead and what I should convert the double array or the int i am trying to compare with. My code is below including the illegal comparing of the double[] and the int.

I am just trying to calculate how many times if any, the users imputed temperature is below or equal to 0 or above or equal to 5.

```
    static void tempCalc()
    {
        Console.Write("Enter a line of coma-separated temperatures: ");
        string line = Console.ReadLine();
        string[] temp = line.Split(',');
        var array = temp.Select(double.Parse).ToArray();

        double sum = array.Sum();
        double numVal = array.Count(); /* Number of values */
        double average = sum / numVal;
        int rangeCount = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            if (array <= 0 && array >= 5)
            {
                rangeCount++;
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Average temperature: {0}", average);
        Console.WriteLine("Minimum temperature: {0}", array.Min());
        Console.WriteLine("There are {0} temperatures below 0 or above 5, rangeCount);

    }
```

Comment: Also open to hearing other ways to check range is between 0 and 5 of the double array.

Comment: Don't you want the `i`th item of `array` for the comparison? At the moment you're comparing an integer to *the whole array*, as the error message is telling you.

Comment: How do you expect a `double[]` and an `int` be compared? You're trying to compare an array and an integer, is that what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Learn to ask questions on SO. Those downvotes really look bad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you "want" to make the below change to your for loop

```
for (var i = 0; i < array.Length; i++)
{
    if (array[i] <= 0 || array[i] >= 5)
    {
        rangeCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: `if (array[i] <= 0 && array[i] >= 5)` is always `false`; it should be `||` instead of `&&`

Comment: @dmitrybychenko you are right. I just had copied it from op. Now fixed the code.

Answer (score 0):

Try keep using *Linq* (since you've already put `array.Count()`, `array.Min()`...), e.g. let's count items in the `array` which are out of `(0..5)` range (both borders are excluded):

```
 //DONE: please, notice || instead of &&
 rangeCount = array.Count(item => item <= 0 || item >= 5);
```

Please, notice, that you don't want to compare the *entire* `array`, but *each item* of it.

```
 Console.WriteLine("Average temperature: {0}", 
   array.Average());

 Console.WriteLine("Minimum temperature: {0}", 
   array.Min());

 Console.WriteLine("There are {0} temperatures below 0 or above 5", 
   array.Count(item => item <= 0 || item >= 5));
```